# Освобождение переменной перед повторным присваиванием

Tags: javascript

Нужно ли (а если не нужно, то полезно ли?) "освобождать" переменную перед тем, как сделать её значением объект другого типа. Например:

```
...  
var d = new Date();  
...  
d=null; // освобождение переменной  
...  
d=new Date(2011,9,23);
```

Comment: 100% ненужно<br>
<small>PS:небойсь на cpp писали? xD</small>

Answer (score 2):

Удалять переменные не нужно, так как в JavaScript реализована автоматическая сборка мусора (неиспользуемая память освобождается автоматически), хотя и возможно. Например,

```
z = 0;
delete z;
```

или

```
z = New Number()
delete z;
```

Есть ли практическая польза, неизвестно, наверное, это можно определить, запуская конкретные тесты на использование памяти.